# ERROR openerp.addons.website.models.ir_http: 500 Internal Server Error: after logout from odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-website

I am using odoo v9 community in Ubuntu 14.04 installation is perfectly done after all works.

but when i install website module of odoo and after i log out from odoo it show following error:
"500: Internal Server Error"
and my log:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo96/addons/website/models/ir_http.py", line 242, in _handle_exception
    response = super(ir_http, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo96/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 147, in _handle_exception
    return request._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo96/openerp/http.py", line 738, in _handle_exception
    return super(HttpRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo96/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 172, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/opt/odoo96/openerp/http.py", line 769, in dispatch
    r = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo96/openerp/http.py", line 316, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo96/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo96/openerp/http.py", line 309, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo96/openerp/http.py", line 888, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo96/openerp/http.py", line 466, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo96/addons/website/controllers/main.py", line 44, in index
    return request.registry['ir.http'].reroute(first_menu.url)
  File "/opt/odoo96/addons/website/models/ir_http.py", line 209, in reroute
    return self._dispatch()
  File "/opt/odoo96/addons/website/models/ir_http.py", line 175, in _dispatch
    key = self.get_page_key()
  File "/opt/odoo96/addons/website/models/ir_http.py", line 94, in get_page_key
    return (self._name, "cache", request.uid, request.lang, request.httprequest.full_path)
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'full_path'"
```

but when i uninstall web module all working well again. how can i solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: How can I uninstall the web module from the command line? My install was working and I made a modification to the website and I get that error now.

Answer (score 2):

Its a dependency issue.
Install a newer version of werkzeug.

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/10184

`pip install werkzeug==0.9.4`

Should do the trick.